# How to disable nginx appending gunicorn transaction data to the http body

Tags: python, http, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I am setting up a flask+gunicorn+nginx webapp and during my initial prototyping stage I have got response from the gunicorn through nginx, however in the process nginx adds the following to the body of the http response, corrupting the html code to be interpreted by the browser.

This is added to top of the body:

```
Server: gunicorn/19.7.1
Date: Thu, 27 Apr 2017 02:05:11 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 12
```

My hello world flask code **test.py** is:

```
from flask import Flask

# Import the fixer
from werkzeug.contrib.fixers import ProxyFix

app = Flask(__name__)

# Use the fixer
app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
        return "Hello World!"
```

I run the following in the directory of test.py to start **gunicorn**:

```
gunicorn test:app
```

and finally restart nginx v1.8.1 with the following **nginx.conf** file:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        location / {
            # Pass the request to Gunicorn
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;

            # Set some HTTP headers so that our app knows where the
            # request really came from
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        }

    }
}
```

What is the proper way for disabling this modification to the response? Am I missing somthing in my nginx conf file?

Comment: This looks like fairly standard HTTP headers... What do you exactly mean by "corrupted"?

Comment: I have to say that I am quite new to webapp development. I understand that the header is valid. But by corrupt I meant that because of this header, when I pass a proper html file to the browser, it is not able to interpret the html and the html code is shown as plain text. It looks like the header, or at least part of it, is added to the body of the http response.

Comment: Makes sense now. There could be a stray empty line somewhere inside headers which signifies "end of headers" to the client, but there's nothing obviously wrong with your config. Could you please attach the output of `curl -I localhost`?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Your clue on looking at the curl response, opened up a whole new can of worms. Curl literally spitted out " weird response". And after looking at the nginx error log, it looked like nginx was expecting an http 1.0 header while gunicorn was outputting http 1.1. Now, note that we are cross-compiling nginx to run on an ARM core and after a good amount of digging it turned out that our binary was bad. ARM gcc is known to have issues with optimization. So, we turned the optimization off, and voila the issue went away.

Comment: Here is the link for the issue https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/899

Comment: Nice one, good to know that you found the root cause :)